# MySQL strange symbols

Tags: mysql, string, casting, symbols, mode

Strange symbols like showed below are appearing in one of my tables.

[strange symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXAt7.png)

Here is its structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `key` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `value` TEXT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`, `key`),
    KEY `id` (`ìd`), 
    CONSTRAINT `table_name_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `table2` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

A commonly executed query:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`(`id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES (47, '78050', '5000')
```

Sometimes value changes to **0** and sometimes changes to these **strange symbols**.

I have been looking for a solution, but no success. Can someone point out a solution, please?